# Diagnosing a connection reset problem

Tags: themes, errors, performance

A couple of weeks ago I purchased a theme from ThemeFuse and installed it in a new WordPress installation. From there, I've been having random errors when accessing or browsing the site. Some requests take too long and other just gives me "connection reset" error.

I've been trying to get support from ThemeFuse and GoDaddy (since I don't really know where the problem lies), and both of them have answered me with not being able to replicate the error and to document it.

Here's the url of the site: http://www.martinycarolina.com/wordpress/

How can I diagnose this error to know where is it coming from, and how can I fix it?

My setup is as follow:
GoDaddy windows hosting plan
WordPress 3.5.1.
ThemeFuse Just Married Theme http://themefuse.com/wp-themes-shop/wedding-wordpress-theme/

Comment: And if you change the theme to _Twenty Twelve_, for instance, everything is working (as fast) as before?

Comment: Yes, On Twenty Twelve the site seems faster.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm unable to load your site (_connection aborted_), both the wordpress subfolder as well as the domain index. Can you access it? Could it be that you are being brute-force attacked right now? Is the link correct?

Comment: The link is correct, i was having the same problem but seems like its back online.